# Show $\vert \vert u \vert \vert_{H^k(\Omega)} \leq C[\vert \vert u \vert \vert_{L^2(\Omega)} + |u|_{H^k(\Omega)}]$ using Deny and Lions lemma

Tags: functional-analysis, partial-differential-equations, sobolev-spaces

Let $u \in H^k(\Omega)$ where $\Omega$ is a bounded Lipschitz domain. I want to show
\begin{equation}
\vert \vert u \vert \vert_{H^k(\Omega)} \leq C[\vert \vert u \vert \vert_{L^2(\Omega)} + |u|_{H^k(\Omega)}]
\end{equation}
where $|u|_{H^k(\Omega)}^2 = \sum_{|\alpha|=k}\vert\vert D^{\alpha}u \vert\vert^2$ and $\vert \vert u \vert \vert_{H^k(\Omega)}^2 = \sum_{|\alpha| \leq k}\vert \vert D^{\alpha}u \vert \vert^2$ using Deny-Lions lemma
\begin{equation}
\inf_{v \in \mathcal{P}_{k-1}}\vert \vert u - v \vert \vert_{H^k(\Omega)} \leq C|u|_{H^k(\Omega)}
\end{equation}
where $\mathcal{P}_{k-1}$ is the space of all polynomials of degree $k-1$.
So far I got
\begin{equation}
\vert \vert u \vert \vert_{H^k(\Omega)} \leq \vert \vert u - v \vert \vert_{H^k(\Omega)} + \vert \vert v \vert \vert_{H^k(\Omega)}
\end{equation}
for all $v \in \mathcal{P}_{k-1}$. Therefore
\begin{equation}
\vert \vert u \vert \vert_{H^k(\Omega)} \leq \inf_{v \in \mathcal{P}_{k-1}}\left( \vert \vert u - v \vert \vert_{H^k(\Omega)} + \vert \vert v \vert \vert_{H^k(\Omega)}\right)
\end{equation}
which doesn't help much.
From this I don't know how to proceed. Also I get
\begin{align}
\vert \vert u \vert \vert_{H^k(\Omega)}^2 &= \vert \vert u \vert \vert_{L^2(\Omega)}^2 + \sum_{1 < |\alpha| < k}\vert \vert D^{\alpha}u \vert \vert_{H^k(\Omega)}^2 + |u|_{H^k(\Omega)}^2 \\
&\leq \vert \vert u \vert \vert_{L^2(\Omega)}^2 + |u|_{H^k(\Omega)}^2 + \sum_{1 < |\alpha| < k}\vert \vert D^{\alpha}(u-v) \vert \vert_{H^k(\Omega)}^2 + \sum_{1 < |\alpha| < k}\vert \vert D^{\alpha}v \vert \vert_{H^k(\Omega)}^2
\end{align}
Now I can't see how to proceed.
**Edit:** It is possible to show by contraposition that there exists a constant $K > 0$ such that
\begin{equation}
||u||_{H^k(\Omega)} \leq K [|u|_{H^k(\Omega)} + ||\Pi u||_{L^2(\Omega)}] \mbox{ for all } u \in H^k(\Omega)  
\end{equation}
where $\Pi : L^2(\Omega) \to \mathcal{P}_{k-1}$ is the $L^2$-projection. From this we get
\begin{align}
||u||_{H^k(\Omega)} &\leq K [|u|_{H^k(\Omega)} + ||\Pi u||_{L^2(\Omega)}] \mbox{ for all } u \in H^k(\Omega) \\
&\leq K \mbox{max}(1,||\Pi||)[|u|_{H^k(\Omega)} + || u||_{L^2(\Omega)}] \\
&= K'[|u|_{H^k(\Omega)} + || u||_{L^2(\Omega)}].
\end{align}
If someone is interested I can write the proof in the answer section.

Comment: The first line is just (one half of) a norm equality. Polynomials play no role in it. I don't see why the detour via the polynomials should be helpful.

Comment: Why is the first line a norm equality?

Comment: You're stating that the $H^k$ norm is bounded from above by some other norm.